# Wiring identical LEDs in parallel

Tags: led, resistors

I am working on a project in which I am powering several 20 ma LEDs off of a 12 volt supply. I therefore need a 470 ohm resistor. The only problem is I don't know how many LEDs I will need. I know that powering say, 4 leds in parallel off of one resistor is a bad idea because of potential current differences, but if all the LEDs come in the same package from an online order, does that mean it would be safer at least?

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B007SJ8XP0?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=ox_sc_act_title_2&smid=A3AGVPZHIH41EE](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007SJ8XP0)

Comment: Putting LEDs in series is more efficient if the supply voltage is high enough.

Comment: Safety considerations are minor; the real problem is that you won't like the way it looks when the brightnesses don't match.

Comment: If they're identical it will work fine. But they're not.

Comment: It's not really a safety issue, it's a burned out bulbs issue

Comment: @Passerby yeah, i was using the word "safe" as in "safe for the bulb"

Comment: Even if they are identical, if your heatsink or environment  cools them unevenly. they will illuminate unevenly, and the hotter one will consume more of the available power...

Comment: weird, everybody has been showing that wiering them in parallel is a horrible idea. I have no idea how I got away with it when i was little and didn't know better (multiple LEDs off of 3 volts either from a battery or computer power supply)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because they are in the same consumer/retail/commercial package does not mean they are from the same production run, or same bin. They are not guaranteed to have the same diode properties for forward voltage or current or brightness.

You can attempt to match them for current and brightness, but the simplest solution is to use one resistor per parallel circuit. Resistors are cheap and small.

The typical ***efficient*** setup for white leds at full brightness 20mA @ 12 Volts is three leds in series with one resistor. Repeat for additional strings of three. You could do two per resistor if you adjust the resistor value.

Comment: so would something like this work, or is that just creating the same problem as the original idea? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8wPABZ2CJFGMXNjYmpzRW9SQUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @blaine that's fine. Not efficient but it works without issues.

Answer (score 3):

Never wire LEDs in parallel if you want reliability and repeatability. This was taken from an article by Maxim on LEDs: -

[image]

It shows a random selection of eight white LEDs. If you decided 3.3 volts was the best voltage to apply to all the paralle LEDs you'd find that one would take 5mA whilst another might only take about 1.5mA - in other words there would be a very noticable range of brightness from the LEDs because it is the current that determines the brightness.

It can be a bit more problematic if you try and have parallel LEDs all sharing the same current limiting resistor. There will always be one LED that hogs most of the current because its natural terminal voltage is lower than the rest and there is a good chance that the current it takes is far in excess of the others and it burns out. What happens next is that the LED with the next lowest natural terminal voltage takes all the current and also burns.

So, place as many LEDs in series as you can and have a common current limiter for that string then step and repeat.

Comment: Would you mind linking to the article? It looks useful.

Comment: @pipe it's here: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3070

Comment: What would happen if you hand matched the LEDs so they all had the same forward drop?  It should be relatively easy to match say 5 LEDs from a bulk pack of 50 using a 1% DMM.  Surely you could run with a 1% current difference.  After all they hand match gain on transistors and valves.

Comment: @PaulUszak I don't really know how well this would work because there doesn't appear to be a motive for doing this. Adding a resistor in series with each isn't a big deal and neither is putting LEDs in series strings.